# SWT draw a table dynamically in a form

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, dynamically-generated

I have a form where in a section of the form I have an action on the toolbar.
Running the action should result in drawing an swt table in the form with dynamic columns and rows.

The problem is that the only way I managed to do this is by creating an empty table initially and then passing the table handle to the action which later will fill it up.

If I have the action code to draw the table the form doesn't expand (scroll) to show the whole table.

Is there any way to achieve what I want without creating an initial table?

The code I have using a Composite is like this:
For creating the composite in the form construction:

```
    gd = new GridData();
    gd.widthHint = 400;
    gd.heightHint = 200;

    tableComposite = new Composite(this.client, SWT.None);
    tableComposite.setLayoutData(gd);
```

In the action code:

```
        GridData gd = new GridData();
    gd.widthHint = 400;
    gd.heightHint = 200;

    if (this.viewer != null) {
        this.viewer.getTable().setRedraw(false);

        while (this.viewer.getTable().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            this.viewer.getTable().getColumns()[0].dispose();
        }
        this.viewer.getTable().dispose();
        this.viewer = null;
    }
    this.viewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    this.viewer.setContentProvider(new FeatureContentProvider());
    this.viewer.setLabelProvider(new FeatureLabelProvider());
    this.viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(gd);
    this.viewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    this.viewer.getTable().redraw();
    this.viewer.refresh();

    List<String> columnNames = getColumnNamesForTable();
    for (String name : columnNames) {
        TableColumn c = new TableColumn(this.viewer.getTable(), SWT.NONE);
        c.setText(name);
        c.setWidth(100);
    }

    this.viewer.getTable().redraw();
    this.viewer.refresh();

    this.viewer.setInput(iterations);
    this.composite.layout(true, true);
```

Where composite is parameter passed from the form in the action code. The table seems to be allocated and the space for the composite also but it's no shown.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this :

- Create an empty `Composite` at the creation of the form at the position where you want to add the Table (a placeholder). It will ont be visible until the table is added.
- When you need to create the table, dispose all the children of the placeholder composite (to remove previous tables for example)
- Create the `Table` using the placeholder composite as parent
- Create the columns and fill the table
- Call `layout(true, true)` on the form (or the top level Composite) to show the table.

**Edit**

From what I see of your code, you need at least to set a layout to the `tableComposite` :

```
tableComposite.setLayout(GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().create());
```

And the relayout should be done at a upper level (maybe using `getParent()` one or several times, until you reach the top level composite, but it would be better if you have it as a field). Example:

```
this.composite.getParent().layout(true, true);
```

Comment: I tried this approach I created a composite in the form:
tableComposite = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.None);
and i pass the tableComposite to the action.
The action code is like this:
this.viewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
this.viewer.setContentProvider(new FeatureContentProvider());
  this.viewer.setLabelProvider(new FeatureLabelProvider());
  this.viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(gd);
  this.viewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
  this.viewer.getTable().redraw();
  this.viewer.refresh();
thic.composite.layout(true,true)
But still is not shown...

Comment: Please post the code in your question, it will be more readable. Also, I think you forgot to set a layout to `tableComposite`

Comment: I tried your suggestions but still the table is not shown... I really cannot understand why...

Comment: @user847988 sorry, no more idea. In theses cases, I usually add border, margins and background colors to the composites to help figure what is missing. Please post the solution when you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

What is missing from the above code is the `redraw` of the `Composite`:

```
this.composite.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution should be:

1) Add the empty table during form creation
2) Exclude the table from UI by setting `exclude` property of the table's `GridData` to true
3) When needed add columns and rows to the table
4) Set the `exclude` property to `false`
5) Redraw or `layout` the container of table.